# Wild cards in a search string

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to build a function as to check wether or not wild cards will be used in a search string.

Example.

```
%name% var search_type = "LIKE"

%name var search_type = "LIKE"

name% var search_type = "LIKE"

name   var search_type = "EQUALS"
```

How can a javascript regex be written to substantiate between the 4 types of examples?

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function test() {

var name = document.getElementById("search").value


}


</script>


</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="search">

<input onclick="test()" type="submit" value="Submit">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a set of actual inputs and output? Your example with `name` is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/idevef/1/edit)

```
function test() {
    var name = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var search_type = '';

    if (name.indexOf('%') > -1) {
        search_type = 'like';
    } else {
        search_type = 'equals';
    }
    alert(search_type);
    return search_type;
}
```

**Update**

The above code will work irrespective of the position of the `%` symbol in the text. If you are interested that it **should** either be at the start OR end OR both, use the below code.
[DEMO Here](http://jsbin.com/idevef/2/edit)

```
function test() {
    var name = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var position = name.indexOf('%');
    var search_type = '';

    if (position === 0 || position === name.length) {
        search_type = 'like';
    } else {
        search_type = 'equals';
    }

    alert(search_type);
    return search_type;
}
```

Comment: Lots of ways to skin a cat more than one way :). Thank you for this example as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your examples, the only indication that `search_type` should be `LIKE` is if the value contains a percentage-sign, `%`. In that case, you could just use `indexOf('%')` to check if it has one:

```
var search_type = (someValue.indexOf('%') > -1) ? 'LIKE' : 'EQUALS';
```

Using your current code:

```
function test() {
    var search_type = (document.getElementById("search").value.indexOf('%') > -1) ? 'LIKE' : 'EQUALS';
    // any other processing required...
    return search_type;
}
```

Additionally, if you wanted to be explicit in that the `%` has to be either at the beginning, end, or both beginning+end of the string and will use *different* modifiers for each, you could use an incremented flag:

```
var search_flag = 0;
var value = document.getElementById('search').value;
if (value.substring(0, 1) == '%') search_flag += 1;
if (value.substring(value.length - 1) == '%') search_flag += 2;

var search_type = (search_flag == 0) ? 'EQUALS' : 'LIKE';
if (search_flag == 1) {
    // % is at beginning of string
    // do stuff...
} else if (search_flag == 2) {
    // % is at end of string
    // do stuff...
} else if (search_flag == 3) {
    // % is at beginning and end of string
    // do stuff...
}
```

This is totally unnecessary if you just need a simple `EQUALS/LIKE` check - but is expandable if you need the specific wildcard locations.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {
    var name = document.getElementById("search").value;
    if( name.substring(0,1) == "%" || name.substring(name.length - 1, name.length) == "%"){
        var search_type = "LIKE";
    }
    else {
        var search_type = "EQUALS";
    }
}
```